# What technologies and programming languages are used to make this website?

Tags: web, flash

I am interested in working for a web-design company. Actually, this one:

http://z-comm.com/

And I'd like to know how their home-page is designed. Just the general way, or maybe if you recognize certain programs used (Dreamweaver, etc). Or Do they use mostly Flash?

Comment: All you need to know to design any webpage is HTML, CSS and javascript along with a brief knowledge of Adobe photoshop.

Comment: Looks like hand-crafted HTML + CSS + jQuery. Did you look at the source code?

Comment: @Blender - My "new" version of Firefox doesn't let me see source anymore!!!! why so?

Comment: @vicky - why photoshop? For nice effects I guess right?

Comment: yes Adel, Photoshop we use for all the graphics, images, effects everything.

Comment: What that  https://wappalyzer.com reports ,it built with http://foundation.zurb.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to be 100% sure what they use on the server side, though the page source refers to a `index.cfm` file, making it highly-likely they're using [Cold Fusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ColdFusion).

The rest seems like manually written HTML, CSS and Javascript.  There's no client-side flash running (at least the home page doesn't refer to any flash components).

Comment: Thank You Very Much - so you can do the front-page sliding pics with JavaScript I assume.

Answer (score 2):

Adel if you're really interested in what technologies we use and working with us give us a call. Ask for the Senior Software Engineer, 504-558-7778.